# Can someone explain the following double assignment involving Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = {n: 1}
var bar = foo
foo.x = foo = {n: 2}

console.log(foo) // {n: 2}
console.log(bar) // ​​​{n: 1, x: {n: 2 }}​​​​​
```

Can someone explain what happened on the third line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `foo.x = foo = {n: 2}` does this:

1. get the object `foo` is referencing
2. assign `{n: 2}` to `foo`
3. assign the object that is now referenced by `foo` to the property `x` of the object determined in step `1.`

This is basically the same code just with a function call where `foo` is overwritten inside of the function:

```js
var foo = {n: 1}
var bar = foo
foo.x = test();

console.dir(bar);

function test() {
   foo = 2;
   return 3;
}
```

`foo` is changed inside of the of `test` function, but the object `foo` determined before that.